# cassandra-snapshotter: not found

Tags: python, cassandra, ansible

i installed cassandra snapshotter using `pip install cassandra_snapshotter`. It's working fine if i run it on terminal with command

```
sudo cassandra-snapshotter --s3-bucket-name=vivek-bucket 
--s3-base-path=cassandra --aws-access-key-id=XXXX --aws-secret-access-key=XXX backup --hosts=172.31.2.85  --user ubuntu
--sshkey=/home/ubuntu/XXXX.pem --cassandra-conf-path=/etc/dse/cassandra --use-sudo=yes --new-snapshot
```

when i tried same command with ansible it ends with error

> "start": "2017-04-25 10:02:39.111333", 
>       "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: cassandra-snapshotter: not found", 
>       "stderr_lines": [
>           "/bin/sh: 1: cassandra-snapshotter: not found"
>       ]
>
> ---

```
- name: snapshot and backup 
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  become: yes    
  tasks:
       - name: taking snapshot
         shell: cassandra-snapshotter --s3-bucket-name=vivek-bucket --s3-base-path=cassandra --aws-access-key-id=XXXX --aws-secret-access-key=XXX backup --hosts=172.31.2.85  --user ubuntu --sshkey=/home/ubuntu/XXXX.pem --cassandra-conf-path=/etc/dse/cassandra --use-sudo=yes --new-snapshot
```

Answer (score 0):

pip installs executables in it's own location. That location is probably not in the search path. You can either set the PATH environment variable in your ansible and extend it to include that location or you could just manually do a 'which cassandra_snapshotter' on the commandline and put the full path to the cassandra_snapshotter executable in your ansible.

Also: I don't think you are using any 'shell' features in that cassandra_snapshotter call. It's better to use https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html when possible.

Comment: i tried that too. its in /home/ubuntu/.local/bin, if i give this in executable , it throwing permission denied. But im running ansible in sudo mode.

Comment: i used shell, because, command gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" without executable. Even now after changing to command and adding executable, some permission is denied. Can you help me in this permission denied?@Bernd

Comment: Well even root has to oblige to the set file permissions. I'm not sure why it's in that home dir, but my guess is that you did the `pip install cassandra_snapshotter` as the user ubuntu and that pip (nowadays) goes ahead and only installs the pkg in the users home dir. That also explains why it's not in the root users path.

Comment: You could either change the files and dirs permission or just redo that pip command as root. I strongly suggest the second.